# Cohen-Macaulay Representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, soft-question, singularity-theory

I came across the book "Cohen-Macaulay Representations" by Graham J. Leuschke and Roger Wiegand, and now I'm wondering if this is an active area of research.
If yes, then

> what are some of the active problems that people are interested in solving, and what connections does it have to other fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules, which seems to be at the center of this book, play a very important role in the theory of *non-commutative resolutions singularities*. Using MCM modules, Van-den-Bergh gave a very interesting reformulation of Bridgeland's proof of Bondal-Orlov conjecture in dimension 3. See [Three dimensional flops and non-commutative rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207170)

For more recent work, you can have a look at any recent paper by Amiot, Donovan, Iyama, Van-den-Bergh-Špenko, Wemyss and their collaborators on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

The classification of CM-finite (meaning there are only finitely many indecomposable CM modules of to isomoprhism) complete local noetherian rings is a wide open problem. The classification is known when the ring is Gorenstein and there is reduces to simple hypersurface singularities of Dynkin type and some exceptional cases.
In the non-Gorenstein case, there are just a handful examples known that are CM-finite and it is a big mystery whether there are more.
The survey article "Auslander's work on Cohen-Macaulay modules and recent developments" by Yuji Yoshino as well as the book by the same author give a nice overview about this open problem.